# Is $GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ algebraic or not?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

The set of $n\times n$ matrices can be identified with $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.

1) Consider the subset $V$ of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n^2+1}$ (note plus one) given by
$$V:=\{(x_{ij},t): \det(x_{ij})\cdot t-1=0\}$$
This is an algebraic subset, indeed $V=V(f)$ where $f=\det(x_{ij})\cdot t-1\in\mathbb{C}[x_{ij},t]$. Then consider the map $\phi:GL(n;\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow V$ sending the matrix $(a_{ij})$ to the $(n^2+1)$-tuple $(a_{ij},\frac{1}{\det(a_{ij})})$. This is a bijection, making $GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ also **algebraic**.

2) $GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ is the complement of the algebraic variety in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ defined by the vanishing of the determinant polynomial, and so is open in the Euclidean topology. Since every affine algebraic variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is closed in the Euclidean topology, we can conclude that the general linear group is **not an algebraic** variety.

So what should I argue from the above reasoning?

1) $GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ is algebraic

2) $GL(n;\mathbb{C})$ is not algebraic

3) It is a common fact that some subsets can be algebraic in one affine space and not algebraic in an affine space of different dimension, so both 1) and 2) can be correct.

Comment: Affine algebraic variety is not the same thing as an algebraic variety. In particular, by definition, an algebraic variety can be an open subset of an affine algebraic variety (these are called quasi-affine algebraic varieties).

Comment: "subset" is not precise.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah, yes. I should have said "Zariski-open" subset.

Comment: This is not what I meant. Varieties are more than just sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general linear group is definitely an affine algebraic variety. It is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2+1}$, but also an open subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$. This is not a contradiction. I suggest that you look at the case $n=1$ more closely and learn the abstract coordinate-free definition of varieties.

Comment: Not only is $GL(n)$ an *algebraic set*  (as subvariety of $\mathbb A^{n^2+1}$), also the maps $(A,B)\mapsto AB$ and $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ are algebraic (i.e. coordinates of the result are polynomials (also defined already over $\mathbb Q$) in the the given coordinates (for the inverse, we are "lucky" to have $\frac1{det A}$ already available per the extra coordinate). So this is in fact an *algebraic group*.

Comment: Question: Does anything regarding connectedness change when we view subsets of $GL(n)$ as embedded in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ or $\mathbb{A}^n$?